# Cocoa - getting privileges within the application

Tags: cocoa, security, authorization

I know how to get the right privileges in order to run an external executable by using the Security framework. This time I want to avoid having a helper tool. So how can I acquire privileges to run my tasks within the application, and not with a helper tool?

Comment: OS X should automatically prompt the user for privileges.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that requires admin privileges? The only thing that you're supposed to create that requires admin privileges is a custom installer, and that is supposed to use a helper tool.

Comment: @Rob I have written a tool which among other things controls the fans. I dom't want others to use that tool, so I'd like to run it within the app.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by coding a helper tool which launches my main application.